# Executing Javascript imported via AJAX (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery .load function to insert some Javascript into my page but I cannot get it to execute. Has anyone any ideas?

The load:

```
$("#seniors").click(function(){
    $("#swfobject").load("ajax/swfobject.php #swfobject", {gallery: "14"}, function() {
    flash();
    }); });
```

Contents of swfobject.php:

```
<?php $gallery = $_POST['gallery']; ?>

<div id="swfobject">
<script type="text/javascript">
 var flashvars = {
    xmlfile: "http://foo.com/API/xml.php?option=<?php echo $gallery ?>",
    xmlfiletype: "Director"
 }
    var params = {
    base: ".",
    menu: "false"

 }
    params.wmode = "opaque";
    var attributes = {}
    swfobject.embedSWF("SSP-AS3.swf", "gallery", "958", "530", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
function flash() {
    alert('flash has run.');
}
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: How do you mean the console? I've checked the net tab in Firebug and I am getting the response I am expecting (the JS code) it is just not being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the jQuery documentation, the callback is invoked after the response is received and the content is added to the innerHTML of the matched element. That doesn't guarantee that the browser's JavaScript interpreter has interpreted any scripts in the content.

You might consider something like this:

```
var loadHandler = function(){
  if(flash){
    flash();
  } else {
    setTimeout(loadHandler, 10);
  }
}

$("#seniors").click(function(){
  $("#swfobject").load("ajax/swfobject.php #swfobject", {gallery: "14"}, loadHandler); 
});
```

That will test whether the flash function exists, and if not wait 10ms, repeating that until the script is in fact interpreted.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but to no avail - you can see the site here - http://racheljhartleyphotography.com/index2.php

Comment: You'll have to forgive me if I miss anything glaringly obvious, I've only really started using jQuery today!

Comment: OK, looks like the problem is that the content isn't actually loading. Looks like the problem is the space between ajax/swfobject.php and #swfobject. Give it a try without that space.

Comment: I've removed the space as suggested, this causes the alert to trigger as expected. If I edit the code so that the flash function encompasses all the JS code the alert still triggers but the .swf file doesn't load.

Comment: Ignore my above comment this error only seems to occur in FF (probably because I'm using the beta version)

Comment: What I find strange is that the jQuery documentation for .load() - http://api.jquery.com/load/ - shows a space inbetween the path and div